# How to download and store a .txt file behind a Javascript link

Tags: python, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I am trying to download the .txt files here: http://www.namejet.com/Pages/Downloads.aspx

But the download links are in a format I have not seen before...

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hlPreRelease0" class="sIcoTxt" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hlPreRelease0','')">Wednesday, September 19, 2012</a>
```

I don't know where to start, I need a script that accesses the downloads page and downloads and stores the file behind this link?

Comment: Try using the charles proxy (http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to capture the request when you click the link, then write a python function replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

The link here is a call to a javascript function `__doPostBack`.

The only way to handle this automatically would be to download the scripts and run the `__doPostBack` function in a JS interpreter with the proper environment. The easiest way to do that is to scripting from inside the browser environment—e.g., with Greasemonkey.

However, you can handle this semi-automatically by downloading and reading the scripts, figuring out what `__doPostBack` does, and seeing if you can implement the same logic in Python with the information you have, so you can transform `javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hlPreRelease0','')` into a URL you can actually download.

To take a very simple example, let's say you found this:

```
function __doPostBack(name, callback) {
  var url = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + '/postbacks/' + name + ".xml";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, false);
  xhr.send();
  var xml = xhr.responseXML;
  if (callback) callback(xml);
}
```

So, you'd do something like this:

```
r = re.compile(r"javascript:__doPostBack\('(.*?)','')")
```

Now, when you get an href that matches this regex, you do something like this:

```
nexturl = 'http://' + urlparse.urlparse(lasturl).netloc + '/postbacks/' + m.groups(1) + '.xml'
u = urllib2.urlopen(nexturl, '')
xml = u.read()
```

If the JS is very convoluted and hard to follow, it may be simpler to use your browser's web development tools to watch what URLs it downloads when you click the link, and then reverse-engineer the transformation. (Or course if you're only grabbing a few files, you can also just find them in the cache from the same place, and then you're done.)